# Can Text To Speech work without button click? Perhaps when your app sets a value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, android-intent

Basically what I'm asking is whether Text To Speech can be invoked if perhaps the value of your variable changes to a specific value and the app reads a string out loud. For example when your game app reaches lives = 0; and the speech reads "Game Over"?

What book can I get that kind of information from?

Comment: You can create method which checks if the lives <= 0 and if they are, just call text to speech. You should call this method every time when the value is changed - you can use getter or even listener for it. I do not know any book about it but I think you don't need it ;-)

Comment: thanx i'll try and give it a go...

Comment: what android book has information on text to speech in general...